# How to reshape data where values of grouped rows become columns? (long to wide?)

Tags: r, casting, reshape, melt

I've searched around for an adequate answer and I don't think that this question has been answered yet. Essentially, I have a data frame in long format that looks like this:

```
    ID  event_type event_value
    123    A          1.1      
    123    A          1.2
    123    A          "Hello"
    234    B          "Hello"
    456    A          2.8
```

Where there are multiple event types with a variety of  values. What I want to do is to reshape the data such that it looks like this

```
    ID  event_type_A_1 event_type_A_2 event_type_A_3 event_type_B_1
    123    1.1         1.2              "Hello"         NA
    234    NA          NA                NA            "Hello"
    456    2.8         NA                NA             NA
```

Such that the new columns extend out as far as the longest event type for any given patient, and the rest are filled with NA. I've mucked around with `spread()` and `cast()`, but for some reason it just isn't clicking. Thanks!

Comment: might look into `data.table`, `plyr` or `dplyr`. Very strange manipulation you want to do here. Off the top of my head you might just try an old fashion for loop. Seems like a very specific problem. If you had a column that kept track of whether this was the 1st, 2nd or 3rd consecutive event type you could use it to index the columns for your new dataset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with `dplyr` and `tidyr`.  The trick is using `group_by` and adding a within group index using `mutate` and `row_number`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data_frame(ID = c(123,123,123,234,456),
                 event_type = c("A","A","A","B","A"),
                 event_value = c(1.1, 1.2, "Hello", "Hello", 2.8))

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(sub_ID = row_number()) %>% 
  unite("ID_type", event_type, sub_ID,remove = TRUE) %>% 
  spread(ID_type, event_value)
```

Breaking down the `dplyr` chain:

1. Make groups by ID
2. Create sub_ID with `row_number()`
3. Combine `event_type` and `sub_ID` with `unite` and remove the original columns
4. `spread()` the ID_type into columns with the values from `event_value`

Comment: I just came across this b/c I need to do this w some data. Thanks so much to Jake for breaking down the dplyr tidyr solution, step by step. It's so helpful.